# Cannot subscript a value of type 'inout [String]' (aka 'inout Array<String>')

Tags: swift3

I see others of questions and answers on this issue, but I'm am still baffled by what is going on. All the examples I've seen are complex and the answers are very specific to that question, so I'm having difficulty parsing out what is specific to the case as opposed to general.

I have a comma delimited string with optional numbers:

```
1,0,,,,0,10.7,,
```

So I use:

```
var parts = oneLine.componentsSeparatedByString(",")
```

I then do various processing to those lines, like...

```
if parts[i].contains("ft") {
    parts[i] = parts[i].replacingOccurrences(of: "ft", with: "")
    if unit[possibleFields()[i]] == "in" { unit[possibleFields()[i]] = "ftin" }
}
```

The code works fine up to this point. But then I want to parse the non-empty values and save them in a dictionary:

```
if parts[0].characters.count > 0 { data["I1"] = Int(parts[0]) }
Cannot subscript a value of type 'inout [String]' (aka 'inout Array<String>')
```

I assume the `inout` is telling me something, but I can't imagine what the issue here is. There is no fix-it either. Something I'm doing is changing parts into something else, but I can't see what that might be, or why this is even an error in the first place (why can't you index an inout array?)

Comment: What type is `data`? This seems like a typical _"shown error obscures the actual error"_ situation. Try to break up your code into smaller pieces around the parts where you're prompted with errors; possibly you'll get prompted with a more on-the-point error (... or this is the actual on-the-point error, but worth a try).

Comment: data is [String:NSNumber], Yes, i should have posted that as well. I have problems deciding what to post in the original question - too much and people skip it, too little and this happens.

Comment: Ok @dfri, following your excellent advice I did this: let dat = parts[0], let con = Int(dat), data["I1"] = con2 - works fine! It's only when you combine them as I did that the error appears.

Comment: For seemingly weird errors, a good first approach is usually to break up the concerned code into smaller pieces.

Answer (score 1):

The actual error is the assignment of Int(parts[0]) to an NSNumber.   That requires a type cast:  Int(parts[0]) as? NSNumber  You probably are using an inout parameter somewhere which caused the error message to become quite misleading.

I checked it in the playground with :

```
  let oneLine = "1,0,,,,0,10.7,,"
  var parts = oneLine.components(separatedBy:",")

  var data : [String:NSNumber] = [:]

  func putInDictionary(_ parts:inout [String])
  {
    if parts[0].characters.count > 0 { data["I1"] = Int(parts[0])  }
  }

  putInDictionary(&parts)
```

And got the error only when passing parts as an inout array of strings.

Adding the type cast solved it.